# How do I install Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store, huawei

I have a rooted Huawei G700-U10 with android 4.2.1. I removed the Android Play Store and Services, but now I need it. How do I reinstall them?

Answer (score 1):

Try flashing the CM10.1 GApps .zip file on the CyanogenMod Wiki (http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps)! CM10.1 = 4.2.1 android version.

When I flashed CM11 on my phone I used the GApps for CM11 on my phone, try it out on yours.

Answer (score -1):

Just download the play store .apk file and install it. If you had it before, you can install it now.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best thing is 
If your friend have an android phone you tell your friend to share the playstore app with an App named MY APP SHARER and install it,
Or u can download it from the internet its just 2 to 4 MB to download, it works seriously.